# Error during wrapup: 置換は 0 列ですが、データは 133 列です　というエラーが解決できない

Tags: r

以下画像のようなcsvファイルからDendrite Length列とFilamentID列のデータを取り出すための関数を書いたのですが、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
DataandIdExtractionfromCSV <- function(path,sectionid,dataname) {
  
  df = read.csv(path, 
                     fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM",
                     stringsAsFactors=F,
                     na.strings="NULL",
  )
  
  df <- na.omit(df)
  # 0,1,2行目を削除
  df2<-df[c(-0,-1,-2),]
  
  
  # 最左列とFilamentIDのdatatypeを変換
  
  df2$dataname <- as.numeric(df2$dataname)
  df2$X.5 <- as.integer(df2$X.5)
  
  
  # Dendrite LengthとFilamentIDをtibble列として再定義、Header(名前)もつける
  tibbledataid = tibble(tibbledataid = df2$dataname)
  tibbledata = tibble(tibbledata = df2$X.5)
  
  # 2列を一つのtibble(行列)に統合
  df_tidy = bind_cols(tibbledataid,tibbledata)
  # 長さと対応するidだけ抽出した行列
  head(df_tidy)
  tidieddfname = paste(sectionid,"_tidy.csv", sep = "", collapse = NULL)
  write.csv(df_tidy, tidieddfname)
  
}
```

これを以下の様に実行すると

```
DataandIdExtractionfromCSV("WT1 x20 ROI1 S ctx 06212021_Statistics/Dendrite_Length.csv","tesuto",Dendrite.Length)
```

```
Error during wrapup:  置換は 0 列ですが、データは 133 列です 
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

以上のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
browse()関数でエラー箇所を調べてみたところ、まず

```
df2$dataname <- as.numeric(df2$dataname)
```

以上の箇所で引っかかっていることが分かりましたが、それ以上何が原因でどうすればよいのか分かりませんでした。

有識者の方々、何卒ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

追記：[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
コード中のX.5という列名？は以下のように自動で付与されていました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問の方に貼らせていただきましたが、df2$X.5はおそらくその左の列の100000xxx系だと思われます。最大値に桁数が近いですが見たところ超えてないようです。。。
もし追加で情報が必要でしたら提供いたしますので、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: すみません、列の位置を間違って捉えていました。しばらくしたら先のコメントは削除します。よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 0):

問題点は `df2$dataname` という表記にあります。この場合、データフレーム `df2` の `dataname` カラムという意味になってしまいます。なので、indirect access な表記に変更します。

```r
  ## df2$dataname -> df2[, dataname] へ変更

  df2$dataname <- as.numeric(df2$dataname)
  =>
  df2[, dataname] <- as.numeric(df2[, dataname])

  tibbledataid = tibble(tibbledataid = df2$dataname)
  =>
  tibbledataid = tibble(tibbledataid = df2[, dataname])
```

また、DataandIdExtractionfromCSV 関数呼び出しの際に指定する第3引数を文字列に変更します。

```r
  ## Dendrite.Length -> "Dendrite.Length" へ変更

  DataandIdExtractionfromCSV("...", "tesuto", Dendrite.Length)
  =>
  DataandIdExtractionfromCSV("...", "tesuto", "Dendrite.Length")
```

Answer (score 0):

質問からかなり時間も経過していますので御参考です。
「CSV ファイルから `Dendrite Length` 列と `FilamentID` 列を取り出して，別の CSV ファイルに書き出す」処理について，`tidyverse` パッケージを用いた記述例を下記に示します。

```
library(tidyverse)
options(pillar.sigfig = 6)

path <- "Dendrite_Length.csv"
sectionid <- "tesuto"
dataname <- "Dendrite Length"

df <- read_csv(path, skip = 2, show_col_types = FALSE)
df
## # A tibble: 7 × 8
##   `Dendrite Length` Unit  Category Depth Level  Time FilamentID           ID
##               <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
## 1          71.1878  um    Dendrite    NA    NA     1  100000373 510000000000
## 2           3.84491 um    Dendrite    NA    NA     1  100000378 510000000000
## 3           2.72817 um    Dendrite    NA    NA     1  100000378 510000000000
## 4          29.3313  um    Dendrite     2     2     1  100000369 510000000000
## 5          34.1316  um    Dendrite    NA    NA     1  100000378 510000000000
## 6          16.0978  um    Dendrite     2     1     1  100000369 510000000000
## 7          28.5015  um    Dendrite     1     1     1  100000369 510000000000

df2 <- df |>
    select(all_of(dataname), FilamentID)
df2
## # A tibble: 7 × 2
##   `Dendrite Length` FilamentID
##               <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1          71.1878   100000373
## 2           3.84491  100000378
## 3           2.72817  100000378
## 4          29.3313   100000369
## 5          34.1316   100000378
## 6          16.0978   100000369
## 7          28.5015   100000369

path2 <- paste0(sectionid, "_tidy.csv")
write_csv(df2, path2)
```

次に，これを基に関数で記述すると下記になります。

```
library(tidyverse)
options(pillar.sigfig = 6)

DataandIdExtractionfromCSV <- function(path, sectionid, dataname) {
    df <- read_csv(path, skip = 2, show_col_types = FALSE)
    df2 <- df |>
        select(all_of(dataname), FilamentID)

    path2 <- paste0(sectionid, "_tidy.csv")
    write_csv(df2, path2)
}
DataandIdExtractionfromCSV("Dendrite_Length.csv", "tesuto", "Dendrite Length")

(read_csv("tesuto_tidy.csv", show_col_types = FALSE))
## # A tibble: 7 × 2
##   `Dendrite Length` FilamentID
##               <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1          71.1878   100000373
## 2           3.84491  100000378
## 3           2.72817  100000378
## 4          29.3313   100000369
## 5          34.1316   100000378
## 6          16.0978   100000369
## 7          28.5015   100000369
```

なお，入力ファイルは下記になります。
Dendrite_Length.csv:

```
Dendrite Length
===============
Dendrite Length,Unit,Category,Depth,Level,Time,FilamentID,ID
71.1878,um,Dendrite,,,1,100000373,5.10E+11
3.84491,um,Dendrite,,,1,100000378,5.10E+11
2.72817,um,Dendrite,,,1,100000378,5.10E+11
29.3313,um,Dendrite,2,2,1,100000369,5.10E+11
34.1316,um,Dendrite,,,1,100000378,5.10E+11
16.0978,um,Dendrite,2,1,1,100000369,5.10E+11
28.5015,um,Dendrite,1,1,1,100000369,5.10E+11
```